# How to show the back of card while flipping?

Tags: css, vue.js

I am trying to create a flipping card, using vue transitions. I would like to display the front / back of the card while flipping like this example https://www.vuescript.com/flipping-info-card/. Right now, with my code below when clicking the back of card is showing up down from where the transition started . How can i resolve this issue so there is a smooth change between front and back?  I think it is a relative / absolute issue.

my css code:

```
      .front_beh-enter-active,.front_beh-leave-active {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: 3s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transition: 3s;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transition: 3s;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transition: 3s;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 3s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.front_beh-enter{
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    opacity:1;
    position: absolute;
    
}
.front_beh-leave
{
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.front_beh-leave-active
{
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

my templates code

```
<template>
    <div class = "flip_container" @click="flip_card">
       <div class="flip w-80 mt-10 ">

    <transition name="front_beh">
      <div
        key="front"
        v-if="!flipped"
        class="front
        w-80 
        h-full 
        bg-green-200 
        shadow-xl 
        rounded-lg "
         >       
        <slot name="front"></slot>
      </div>
     
      <div
        key="back"
        v-if="flipped"
        class=" back
        w-80
        h-full
        bg-blue-200 
        shadow-lg 
        rounded-lg
        "
      >
        <slot name="back"></slot>
      </div>
      </transition>
      </div>
      </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just install the node component you linked to?
If you want to do this in plain html/css maybe this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_flip_card.asp can help you, I added the important code for flipping below

```
.YOUR-FRONT-CLASS:hover .YOUR-BACK-CLASS {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Comment: the project i am working needs to use vue transitions and neither of these projects are using them. So i cant just install this component.

Comment: Depending on the license you can still copy source code or get inspiration for what to do. You don't have to reinvent it.

Comment: well again i have see a lot of source code and they are using pure css and html. Is there any doc for using vue transitions so i can read?

Comment: The Vue docs has a part about transitions https://v3.vuejs.org/api/built-in-components.html#transition (Vue 3) https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#transition (Vue 2)